# Is it possible to edit related tables in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: attribute-table, editing, arcgis-online, relationship-class

I would like to make an editable web map where the user can create a feature then fill in information in a related table all in ArcGIS Online.  Is there any way to do  this?  So far, my research says no, but my organization is sold on the idea and would like to find a way to do this if there is one.

I am aware that it is possible to edit a related table using the ArcGIS Collector App as explained [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/18/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/), but we would like to work with ArcGIS Online on a desktop if possible.

Even if this is not currently possible, I'd like to know definitively so I can start exploring other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to follow up-- I have contacted ESRI and it is not possible to edit/update related tables in ArcGIS Online as of this writing, but it is something that is currently being worked on for a future update.

Comment: You can look into the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, which supports that kind of stuff. Although that involves programming, of course.

Comment: So far as I know, the Javascript API doesn't support this either; a search for "relat*" on the API website shows only `RelationParameters` and `RelationshipQuery`. Sniffing the network traffic on a device running Collector might let you hack something together based on the request content, but that's definitely not supported. :) The Python API does have some support for this, but  then you're into programming in ArcMap anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did find a round-about way to edit related tables on ArcGIS online. You can create a filter for the feature or features you wish to edit then run a field calculate on that particular feature. I used the OBJECTID field to select a particular feature and calculate values.

I am sure with some smart programming in the JavaScript API this could be converted to a tool to edit related features.

This however does not allow you to create new records in your related table, only edit existing records.